# How to set multiple directories with using one file dialog function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using function to set database directory at Excel with FileDialog, But I have to set about 20 different database directory

I set up one of it with `SettingsSheet.databaseDirectory0 = sItem`, but for the others, I don't want to write the same function for each of them isn't there any 
parametric solution to set them to one function?

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fdo As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fdo = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fdo
        .Title = "Select a Directory"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        SettingsSheet.databaseDirectory0.Value = sItem 
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fdo = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd start accepting some answers to your questions. It is likely to encourage people to help.

Comment: @SJR i'm trying to test all answers and vote them.

Comment: OK that's good, but why not accept answers too - it is the basis of the how the site works as I understand it.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but there is no such thing as `settingsWorkDirectory0`

Comment: @braX sorry dude it was happened when i copied from my setting working directory code now it's ok. settingsWorkDirectory0 is a ActiveX textbox element.

Comment: @braX i have 20 textbox with file dialog button, i will push the button and select the database directory and it writes the path this textbox. But as you can see for all 20 dataabase directory i'll be using same function as you can see above. I'm asking this: i can do it for one database with the code. But i should do it parametric to avoid copy same code 20 times. The key point is reference of textbox settingsWorkDirectory0 it's unique and i don't know how can i make it parametric for settingsWorkDirectory01, settingsWorkDirectory2, settingsWorkDirectory3 ...... settingsWorkDirectory20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it the control. Something along the lines of this:

```
Function GetFolder(txt As Control) As String
    Dim fdo As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fdo = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fdo
        .Title = "Select a Directory"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        txt.Value = sItem 
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fdo = Nothing
End Function
```

This pseudo-code demonstrates how to make the function generic. See how I'm passing the control to the function and then referencing that instead of the `databaseDirectory0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can return sItem to the parent caller and set

SettingsSheet.databaseDirectory0n.Value = functionName(txt as Control)

Does this make sense?